# T-SQL IF CLAUSE SYNTAX

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to build up a sp for scheduling a mailing list depending on various parameters, and it is working fine up to this point:

```
DECLARE
@out_desc VARCHAR(1000),@out_mesg VARCHAR(10),@tableHTML  NVARCHAR(MAX),@frequency INT,@userName    NVARCHAR(50),@userEmail NVARCHAR(50),
@category NVARCHAR(50),@range INT,@geoid int,@IsDeleted BIT,@searchCity NVARCHAR(50);

DECLARE C1 CURSOR READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT [userEmail], AspNetUsers.[UserName], [frequency], [category], [range], [geoid], [searchCity], [IsDeleted] FROM WishLists
JOIN AspNetUsers ON WishLists.userEmail = AspNetUsers.Email

OPEN C1
FETCH NEXT FROM C1 INTO
@userEmail, @userName,@frequency, @category,@range, @geoid, @searchCity, @IsDeleted
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
      IF @frequency = 1
      BEGIN
            SET @tableHTML =  
    N'<H1>Hello' +  @userName +
    N'<table border="1"><tr><th>Department</th>th>Name</th><th>Description</th><th>Place</th></tr>' +  

        CAST (( SELECT td = c.Name, '',   td = p.Name, '',   td = p.Description, '', td = @searchCity
                  FROM Products as p JOIN Categories AS c ON c.ID = p.CategoryID  JOIN AspNetUsers as u ON u.ID = p.UserID WHERE (p.IsApproved = 'true' AND p.IsDeleted = 'false'  AND u.Email = @userEmail) AND DateExpire > convert(date, getdate())
                  FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE   
        ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) 
    +  
    N'</table>' ; 

    EXEC sp_send_mail
    ...
```

This works as expected.
Now that I have tested the emailing function I need to further elaborate the SELECT with another "IF" clause where a specific geolocation has been selected.

I'm trying to insert this new IF clause adding another SELECT this way:

```
    ...
N'<th>Place</th></tr>' +  

        CAST (
IF @geoid = 0 (
    (SELECT td = c.Name, '',  
                        td = p.Name, '',  td = p.Description, '', td = @searchCity
                  FROM Products as p 
                  ...)
                  FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE   
        ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
)
ELSE
    (...geoid > 0 => another select here...)
    ) 
    +  
    N'</table>' ;
```

but just inserting the
`IF @geoid = 0 ()`
block it looks like there's something wrong with the syntax.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

use the case statement instead of IF as below

```
N'<th>Place</th></tr>' +  

        CAST (
CASE WHEN @geoid = 0 THEN (
    (SELECT td = c.Name, '',  
                        td = p.Name, '',  td = p.Description, '', td = @searchCity
                  FROM Products as p 
                  ...)
                  FOR XML PATH('tr'), TYPE   
        ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
)
ELSE
    (...geoid > 0 => another select here...)
    ) 
    +  
    N'</table>' ;
```

because the If statement can not be used inside other operations like SELECT or SET

Something Like this

```
DECLARE @V_String VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT 
    @V_String = CASE WHEN SalesOrderID%2 = 1
                    THEN (SELECT DueDate FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader FOR XML PATH(''))
                ELSE (SELECT ShipDate FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader FOR XML PATH('')
                ) 
                END
    FROM SalesLT.SalesOrderHeader S

SELECT
    @V_String
```

Comment: Thanks Jayasurya, got it. Working on your suggestion.

Comment: Not sure CASE works in this case. As a matter of fact I don't need to switch inside a SELECT. I need to execute totally different selects depending on a IF clause.

Comment: Then maybe you should try something like this
 IF((condition)
BEGIN
  <Your Code>
END
ELSE IF (Condition2)
BEGIN
  <Your Code>
END
ELSE
BEGIN

END

Comment: Sure this works but that way I have to duplicate the entire code this wa, from "SET @tableHTML =" to "N'</table>' ;".
I thought there could be a better way to write it changing only the code inside the SELECT, but I cannot manage to do it that way.

Comment: Sure that works but I have to duplicate the entire code that way from "SET @tableHTML =" to "N'</table>' ;" while I was trying to change only the variable code part , that is the SELECT

Comment: but inside the case, you can use the select statements. So I don't see any issues with using the case. For each case you can have different select statements

Comment: I see, but the example you posted doesn't work (syntax error). Could you post a working example of a CASE statement including different SELECTs?

Comment: I have added a sample code above using the AdventureWorksLT2008R2 Database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139028/discussion-between-luke-and-jayasurya-satheesh).